# Axes definition in fviz_mclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I haved used `Mclust` package to perform latent cluster analysis. When visualizing the clusters, the axes labels are `Dim1` and `Dim2`. What do the labels mean or indicate? Is it PCA dimensions? Here is an example showing the cluster plot - https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/factoextra/reference/fviz_mclust.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is the first two principal component, the percentages in the labels mean the proportion of variance explained by each component. You can recreate it like this:

```
library(mclust)
library(factoextra)
data("diabetes")
mc <- Mclust(diabetes[, -1])

fviz_mclust(mc, "classification", geom = "point")
```

[image]

```
pca = prcomp(scale(mc$data))
pca_plot = data.frame(pca$x,cluster = factor(mc$classification))
variance_explained = round(100*(pca$sdev^2)/sum((pca$sdev^2)),1) 

ggplot(pca_plot,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,col=cluster)) + 
geom_point()+
xlab(paste("PC1 : ",variance_explained[1],"%"))+
ylab(paste("PC2 : ",variance_explained[2],"%"))
```

[image]